# Check box ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have check box and want send value check box (0 or 1) and in entity where clicked check box on some action

```
        <input class="searchType" type="checkbox" name="SharingNotification" id={{ taskExecution.id }}>
        <label class="searchtype2label">{{ taskExecution.id }}</label>
    </input>


$('.searchType').click(function(event) {
    if(this.checked){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/app_dev.php/api/customer/customers',
            data: {
                id: event.target.id,
                value: event.target.value
            },,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('it worked');
                alert(data);
                $('#container').html(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('it broke');
            },
            complete: function() {
                alert('it completed');
            }
        });

    }
});
```

in request in action

```
request = {Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag} [1]
 parameters = {array} [2]
  id = "1"
  value = "on"
```

I try like this

```
event.target.id
"1"
event.target.value
"on"
```

but why "on" I think can be 1 or 0

how to send data like key(id entity) => value(value check box) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the object to send like this :

```
var objToSend = {};
objToSend[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).is(":checked");
```

And send your data like

```
data: objToSend
```

Comment: hot to change on to integer ?

Comment: @shuba.ivan, you need to use this : `objToSend[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).is(":checked")==true? 1:0;`

Comment: @R3tep if I need in request like `ids` => [key => value] ?

Comment: @shuba.ivan like `objToSend[$(this).attr('id')] = { key: value }` ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use a `dictionary` and send it to `code-behind`.

```
var dictionary= {};
dictionary[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).is(":checked")==true? 1:0;
```

And pass it to `ajax` data like this:

```
data:dictionary
```